# Authenticate on a on-premise webservice

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I am having trouble with authentication in my asp-net web service. This service has an angular gui and some mvc api.

This service will be deployed on multiple servers inside my organisation windows or linux (or even docker). This seems to prevent me from using basic active directory authentication. Important part is I don't know before deployment the target ip:port of deployment.

I am trying to add an azure active directory based authentication.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
}
```

Everything works fine until I get into the Reply Url part of the authent process. It seems I can't find a way to avoid using a reply url.

In dev environement I have to add localhost as a valid reply url to my app and everything works fine. But what about future deployment? It seems very painfull to maintain a complete and up to date list of all the alive servers.

Is there a way to do the complete auth process client side and then go back to back end only when the final token has been received? I then suppose that the backend would have to validate the token against the authority has it was not implied in the process but that's fine.

What am I missing here?